# Issues with a service running on a different process

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service

I am trying to start a service in a new process, so it would stay alive when the app closes.

I have an activity called MainScreen, and an IntentService called BackgroundSensorService.
Here is the manifest definition of the service:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.BackgroundSensorService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":backgroundSens" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Here is the code snippet that runs the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, BackgroundSensorService.class);
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
startService(intent);
```

When I try to set a breakpoint in the HandleIntent method, I never reach it.
I tried to set a breakpoint in onCreate, but I never reach that one either.
The weird this is, if I remove the 'process' tag from my service, everything works perfectly.

I am breaking my head over this issue...

Note: I am trying to mimic the behavior of the whatsapp sample service, that keeps track of incoming messages even while the app is closed. The service should run in the background, and have no GUI.

Comment: If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, **provided that it has permission to do so**. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @Skynet. I tried it out, but it does not fix my problem. Still, good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Intent service is meant to run in background though - even if your app is not on the stack

Answer (score 0):

I got a working example of a unbound service running after the application is closed here:
https://github.com/kweaver00/Android-Samples/tree/master/Location/AlwaysRunningLocation

Android Manifest code in application tag:

```
<service
    android:name=".YourService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:description="@string/my_service_desc"
    android:label="@string/my_infinite_service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.weaverprojects.alwaysrunninglocation.LONGRUNSERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Start service:

```
Intent servIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourService.class);
startService(servIntent);
```

The example here, called every time the location changed (using mock locations) and the app was not opened

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Keith. I don't really understand how did you get the service to stay up. You didn't specify it will run on a different process.
If you kill your app via the process manager, will your service still run? Because that is my main issue here. If so, please elaborate on what tags in the manifest gave you this behavior

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Android services, once you kill the app, the service will be killed as well. You can however force it to restart itself.

In your service, you should be using the onStartCommand method that returns the type of service you'd like to use.
The main options are:

START_NOT_STICKY: tells the OS not to recreate the service if its closed.

START_STICKY: Tells OS to restart the service if its closed (sounds like you want this one).

```
@Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
   return START_STICKY; //restarts service when closed
}
```

When the service is restarted however, all parameters passed to it will be reset. If, like me, you need to keep track of certain data, you can use SharedPreferences to save and read values (there might be a better way, but this worked for me).

Comment: Thank you for the info, but this is not what I am looking for. If I run the service on a different process, it should not close when the app closes, since that only kills the main process